# Docker: How to use bash with an Alpine based docker image?

Tags: bash, docker, shell, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I created a docker image from `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine` and I want to use `bash`, rather than `sh` as my shell, however when I try to execute simple commands I get the following errors:

```
RUN bash
/bin/sh: bash: not found

RUN ./gradlew build
env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory
```

Comment: For googlers: `docker run --rm -i -t alpine /bin/sh`

Comment: Start container ( interactively): docker exec -it  container_id /bin/sh

Comment: Possibly this could get edited to include the phrase "and I want to use bash, rather than sh as my shell"?

Comment: Another option is to alias ash to bash. `ln -s /bin/ash /bin/bash`. But you are setting yourself up for confusing errors :)

Answer (score 685, accepted):

Alpine docker image doesn't have bash installed by default. You will need to add the following commands to get `bash`:

```
RUN apk update && apk add bash
```

If you're using `Alpine 3.3+` then you can just do:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
```

To keep the docker image size small. (Thanks to comment from @sprkysnrky)

If you just want to connect to the container and don't need bash, you can use:

```
docker run --rm -i -t alpine /bin/sh --login
```

Comment: The `apk upgrade` is not required.

Comment: I prefer use the recomendation of @Yuva using  `RUN /bin/sh` instead of  `RUN bin/bash`

Comment: That is entirely up to you, many people need `bash` specific feature.

Comment: why should I use the `--no-cache` option?

Comment: @aurelia, not to keep the downloaded app/package in the cache. usually, when you install an app in Linux with `apk`/`apt-get` they download the app first and install it but do not remove it after the installation is completed, which takes storage space.

Comment: Easier solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72867431/4162689

Answer (score 454):

Try using `RUN /bin/sh` instead of bash.

Comment: OP asked for bash. sh is not bash.

Comment: But this is very useful comment anyway - most people will be fine with sh - and it does not require additional 50mb of image size

Comment: Easy and straightforward. Most times we only need to run shitty commands (ls, ps, whatever), sh covers those scenarios. thanks!

Comment: @kboom comments go in the comment section. this is not an answer to the original question.

Comment: @kboom the `bash` package adds about 4MB to the size of `alpine:3.8`, roughly doubling it, but still far from 50MB.

Comment: @kboom I can confirm that adding bash adds about 4MB, not 50MB. I just changed `RUN apk add --no-cache python` to `RUN apk add --no-cache python bash`, which added 4MB.

Comment: This answer takes in account that OP was confused about `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash`; which will help people in any case.

Comment: @phil294 I was looking for bash because I was expecting bash. Having sh instead is a perfectly acceptable alternative.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer. At the same time I agree that the accepted answer should include a comment that if possible one should stick to `sh` rather than install `bash` as it increases the size of the image.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. I didn't want to rebuild my image just to check on a file inside the container. I'm sure that many people are looking for bash but any alternative is also perfectly fine.

Comment: no. it's not. the `/bin/sh` in alpine is actually a symbol link to `/bin/busybox`. it's still ash

Comment: Confirmed that bash adds about 4MB, not 50MB. If you experiment with a simple Dockerfile `FROM alpine` and `RUN apk update && apk add bash` the resulting image is only 9.65 MB.  Alpine alone is about 5.32 MB. Of course if you `FROM python:alpine` you are going to get your 50MB but that's because of the Python in the image, not bash.

Comment: `FROM nginx:1.22.0-alpine` Adding Bash changes the size from 22.1 to 23.7. `/bin/sh` is extremely limited, it does not even support UP/DOWN arrows so it'll be a total PITA to shell into to debug.

Answer (score 29):

```
RUN /bin/sh -c "apk add --no-cache bash"
```

worked for me.

Comment: The initial part of the RUN command is unnecessary. You can just write `RUN apk add --no-cache bash` directly

Answer (score 14):

To Install bash you can do:

```
RUN apk add --update bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

If you do not want to add **extra size** to your image, you can use `ash` or `sh` that ships with alpine.

Reference: https://github.com/smebberson/docker-alpine/issues/43

Answer (score 14):

**Option : Start from Bash**

The [official bash image](https://hub.docker.com/_/bash) is based on Alpine and prevents you from needing to install bash every time. Simply use

`docker pull bash`

This was first published on Oct 19, 2016 at 6:43 pm.

**Option : Use your Existing Base Image**

If you want to use your existing base image, while avoiding the need to install bash on every container boot, then you can add this to your Dockerfile.

```
# Use openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as the base image
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Install bash package
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
```

Comment: I have upvoted this answer

Comment: @anubhava I have upvoted your upvoting.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the option (for instance if you are just creating the script), using an alpine image with bash installed such as [alpine-bash](https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-bash) might be clever.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because this docker image uses Busybox.
Busybox is a popular minimal Docker base image that uses [ash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell), a much more limited shell than bash.

If you use sbt-native-packager you just need to add support

```
enablePlugins(AshScriptPlugin)
```

Answer (score 0):

`USER root`

`RUN apk add --no-cache bash`

`/bin/sh` is good, but not enough to use. Sometimes `/bin/bash` is necessary. So I used above code to install bash in alpine.