# Jenkins declarative pipeline can't find some scripts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have written a Jenkins pipeline where the relevant parts looks as follows:

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        dockerfile true 
    }
    triggers {
        pollSCM('H 1 * * 1-5')
    }
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactNumToKeepStr: "${NUMBER_OF_ARTIFACTS_TO_KEEP}"))
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES')
        timestamps()
    }

    stages {
        stage('Metadata') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'java -version'
                }
                script {
                    sh './mvnw -v'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh './mvnw --batch-mode clean install'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Archive artifacts (develop/master)') {
            when {
                anyOf {
                    branch 'master'
                    branch 'develop'
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    sh './package.sh'
                }
                archive '**/target/*.jar'
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.deb'
            }
        }
    }


    post {
        always {
            deleteDir()
        }
        failure {
            sendNotifications currentBuild.result
        }
        unstable {
            sendNotifications currentBuild.result
        }
    }
}
```

And my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache dpkg openjdk8
```

All scripts run fine, *except* package.sh where I get the following log in the output:

> 07:47:25 [chx-sync_-sync_master-A2F53LY4I2X54TLDEU2Z2PXI423NI6FODHQDS7CRIKCCNDF5UGOA] Running shell script
>   07:47:25 + ./package.sh
>   07:47:25 /home/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/chx-sync_-sync_master-A2F53LY4I2X54TLDEU2Z2PXI423NI6FODHQDS7CRIKCCNDF5UGOA@tmp/durable-dbcb4143/script.sh: line 1: ./package.sh: not found

I can't figure out why all scripts except this one would work. They are all located in the root of the project in Git. Is there some command in my pipeline that would change the working directory, or what is going on here?

**EDIT:**

I'm guessing the shebang in package.sh might be relevant? It is `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Does `package.sh` have correct `x` permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from this answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40944512). I simply changed the using `#!/bin/sh` and it is working.