# Docker cannot find module /bin/bash

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I am trying to build a docker image for a nodejs web backend which currently looks like this:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/smart-brain-api

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

When I do `docker run -it` after building an image, I get this weird error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/bin/bash'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

however if I edit the docker file and change CMD ["/bin/bash"] to CMD ["/bin/sh"] everything works

I am working on a macbook air 13, I don't know if that could be a factor.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`alpine` images doesn't have `bash` installed out of box. You need to install it separately.

```
RUN apk update && apk add bash
```

[How to use bash with an Alpine based docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944479/how-to-use-bash-with-an-alpine-based-docker-image/40944512)

Answer (score 3):

Like the other answer said you need to install bash first as alpine doesn't comes with bash installed. You need to install it with:

```
RUN apk update && apk add bash
```

Then you can switch the default shell from sh to bash with this line in your dockerfile

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

The dockerfile should look like something like this

```
FROM node:10-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add bash
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
CMD bash # If you want to override CMD
```

Then you can launch you container with this line

```
docker run -it --rm <image-name> bash
```

or if you have overrided CMD you can simply do

```
docker run -it --rm <image-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try a `which bash` in your working container but there is most likely no Bash in this container image.

Try using a less slim image.