# Docker golang + ffmpeg Failed to execute command

Tags: docker, go, ffmpeg

Hi I am using the following docker image:

```
FROM golang:alpine3.18
```

With ffmpeg: (probably here I am missing something)

```
RUN apk add --no-cache ffmpeg
```

However when trying to execute the following:

```
cmd := "ffmpeg -i Untitled.mp4 -vf \"fps=5,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos\" -c:v pam -f image2pipe - | convert -delay 5 - -loop 0 -layers optimize test.gif"
_, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", cmd).Output()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to execute command: %s", err))
}
```

I get this error:

```
 Failed to execute command: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: How to use bash with an Alpine based docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944479/docker-how-to-use-bash-with-an-alpine-based-docker-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alpine docker image doesn't have bash installed by default. It uses the Ash shell instead

The answer is already here [Docker: How to use bash with an Alpine based docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944479/docker-how-to-use-bash-with-an-alpine-based-docker-image)

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried to access the container and exec "bash" by terminal?
Some containers have only "sh" command available by default.
Otherwhise when you access the container check the files that you are trying to execute with the bash command are there in the container or are well linked in your machine with volumes.