# Why file cannot be found after being copied to a container

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have a dockerfile like the following:

```
FROM golang:1.19 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -v -o "hello-bin"


#FROM scratch
FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/hello-bin /app/hello-bin
COPY --from=builder /app/start.sh /app/start.sh
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT  [ "./start.sh" ]
```

which simply build a binary from a hello-world go file. However, when I try to run this container with the following docker-compose setting, it showed `exec ./start.sh: no such file or directory`.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  hello:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

The structure of the directory is

```
❯ tree .
.
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── go.mod
├── hello
├── init.go
└── start.sh
```

So the `start.sh` should be loaded to the `builder` container via the `COPY . .` line as well, and it should be passed to the second container via the `COPY --from=builder /app/start.sh /app/start.sh`.

For context, the content of `start.sh` is as follows:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

_main() {
  echo "start"
}

_main "$@"
```

My most confusing part is that, if I change it to `CMD [ "ls", "-l" ]` in the Dockerfile, it actually prints out

```
awesomeproject3-hello-1  | -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       1819562 May 19 02:41 hello-bin
awesomeproject3-hello-1  | -rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            51 May 19 02:39 start.sh
```

and also if I change it to `ENTRYPOINT [ './hello-bin' ]` in the Dockerfile, the binary runs successfully as well. I just can't figure out why it says there's no `./start.sh`.

---

UPDATE: inspired by @larsks, I noticed if I change the header of `./start.sh` from `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh`, it magically worked. I am still confused what the underlying issue here, and if I want to keep the bash header, how should I fix the docker file?

Comment: What are the permissions on `start.sh`? What are the contents of `start.sh`? In particular, what does the `#!` line look like? If you inspect the image filesystem, do you see the files in `/app` as expected?

Comment: @larsks Thanks for responding -- 1. permission for `start.sh` is `-rwxrwxrwx`, as has been shown after I change it to `CMD [ "ls", "-l" ]` in the dockerfile; 2. the content of start.sh is just simply a `echo hello` with the `#!/bin/bash` header; 4. I believe `CMD [ "ls", "-l" ]` already showed the files in `/app`

Comment: @larsks oh but I just tried changing the header to `#!/bin/sh`, it magically worked! But I'm still confused why?? The error message `exec ./start.sh: no such file or directory` is very misleading as it seems to say that the file doesn't exist at all! Also, if I want to keep the bash header, how should I fix the dockerfile? (updating the question body as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error happening because you have used `#!/bin/bash` in your `start.sh`.

Alpine docker image doesn't have bash installed by default. It uses the [Busybox](https://busybox.net/about.html) shell instead.

you can install `bash` in your container. See [Docker: How to use bash with an Alpine based docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944479/docker-how-to-use-bash-with-an-alpine-based-docker-image)

or you can change `#!/bin/bash` into `#!/bin/sh` as you noted in your comment on the question.

Comment: Thank you so much for saving my life! Adding `RUN apk add --no-cache bash` to the docker file fixed it. Though I think the `exec ./start.sh: no such file or directory` error is very misleading ...

Comment: The script you show doesn't use any non-standard features and I would change the shebang line to `#!/bin/sh` (not `ash`, and you won't need to `apk install` anything).